# Meteor get Steam account information

Tags: meteor, openid, steam

I would like to add steam_id to already registered account. Steam uses OpenId to verify user, what is the best way to do it ? (I don't want to use steam account as login option, just add it to profile) I was trying to modify accounts-... as a template but couldnt make it work :/
Thanks !